# What does a plane in spherical coordinates look like as seen in cartesian coordinates

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, plane-geometry, spheres

In working with spherical coordinates $\rho$, $\phi$,$\theta$, where $\phi$ is the spherical angle, one could plot a simple flat plane in the space of the spherical coordinates.

**For example:**

In the basis ($\rho$, $\phi$,$\theta$), I have three points. They are
(1,0,0), (0,$\pi/2$,0), (0,0,$\pi/4$). Clearly these 3 points define a plane/triangular region in this basis.

My question is, however, ***what does this region look like in cartesian space?*** Is it simply a spherical patch of area?

Is the area of this region given by one half the cross product of the vectors:

Area = (1/2) | (<1,0,0> - <0,$\pi/2$,0>) x (<0,0,3> - <0,$\pi/2$,0>) |?

I have been thinking about this for quite some time now and have not yet come up with an answer. Help would be appreciated.